# Pure C Code For Video Encoding

Tags: c, encoding, h.264, decoding

I'm doing some computer hardware architectural explorations and I was eager to test different tasks on my prototype. so I need some code to simulate the task of video encoding and/or decoding (H264 would be perfect but other codecs are also ok).

Is there anything that I can use? It doesn't have to be exactly encoding/decoding, just some code that can roughly estimate the same workload with same kind of computations so I can get some performance/power consumption results.

Oh yeah and it's gotta be in "pure C", and without using any sophisticated libraries (math.h is fine) since I'm gonna have to put that onto a hardware module.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Voters to close: I fail to see how this is not a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [libavcodec](http://libav.org/). It is [pure C](http://libav.org/faq.html#I_0027m-using-Libav-from-within-my-C_002b_002b-application-but-the-linker-complains-about-missing-symbols-which-seem-to-be-available_002e).